# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI, No action was found on the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I am new to MVC and C#, so sorry if this question seems too basic.

I have trouble with calling 'action' in web api.

I don't know why my method below always throws an error: 
"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44358/api/RollUp/TrainingImage".
 While other methods ([HttpGet]) run normally

```
 public class RollUpController : ApiController
 {
    .
    .
    . orther method


    [HttpPost]
    public string TrainingImage(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }
 }
```

This is the file webApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This is the result when I test it by PostMan : [test by postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQskr.png)

Comment: Can you show the headers that postman sends too? And does the result change if you declare `public string TrainingImage(string id)`, or alternatively `public string TrainingImage([FromBody]string name)` - i think simple types are expected in the URL rather than the body, by default

Comment: Also think we may need to check that the headers postman sends imply the body is json encoded

Comment: please call this url https://localhost:44358/api/RollUp/TrainingImage?name=myname and tell me what happened

Comment: I don't know why, but when I change [HttpPost] to [HttpGet] at the action in controller and call URL:  localhost:44358/api/RollUp/TrainingImage?name=myname then it runs normally